React start async submit process only once
We have a form with a submit button, and the OnClick starts the submit process. This submit process is async, takes long. During that process, we should not let to start the submit again, causing multiple submits by clicking fast enough.
The submit process returns with a bool at the end - flagging is the submit process was success or not. If not - the submit process can be re-executed later.
  export default function FormFooter({onSubmitClick}:{onSubmitClick: ()=>Promise<boolean>}): ReactNode {
    const [inProgress, setInProgress] = useState(false);

    function execClickOnce(): void {
      if (!inProgress) {
        setInProgress(true);
      }
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (inProgress) {
        onSubmitClick().then((enableAgain) => setInProgress(!enableAgain));
      }
    }, [inProgress]);

    return (
      <button type="button"  onClick={execClickOnce} />
    );
  }

We used useEffect to determine if the setInProgress has been changed, and start the submit process asynchronously.
Somehow I does not like this code. Seems too complex - however seems works good. Anyone has a better idea how to solve the issue in a more simplified way?
Also - it is adviced to add the onSubmitClick to the useEffect dependency array, but in this special case I don't really think it is important - as I don't really care about the current value of the onSubmitClick, does not really matters if it has been changed or not. What do you think about it?
I would be glad to receive any advice, clarification about the code above. Thank you guys!

I will remove the useEffect and move the following code in execClickOnce: setInProgess(true); onSubmitClick().finally(() => setInProgress(prev => !prev)); Looking at your code, it seems that you are expecting onSubmitClick to return a promise that fulfills with a boolean value that you use to change inProgress state. You don't need to do that, just use the finally block as shown in this comment.

I think if the user clicks fast-enough, multiple events are raised, and therefore the execClickOnce will be fired multiple times, so the process will be started multiple times.

Call onSubmitClick only if if (!inProgress) { is true and also disable the button after use click and enable it in the finally block in the code shared in my previous comment.

Yeah, I thought that. The problem is, that this will work only if the setState cause the re-rendering, and the inProgress gots its new value. If the component current rendering has the inProgress=false, and the user clicks fast - multiple times the execClickOnce is called, and several of them inProgress is still false. Then - finally, the re-render happens, the inProgress becomes true, and no more start happens. But until that - depending on the user how fast can click - multiple start happens.

use the  isDisabled funtion. make a state and once progress is over , update the state to udpate the disbabled value. this would be simpler way to handle this

Problem is not about to re-enable the button when the process is over. Our tester was able to click and fire onClick event more than once before the re-render and therefore before the button becomes disabled. This is what I want to achieve - preventing starting the process multiple times.
